# bootstrap sidebar toggle speed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar

I just have a simple question about adjusting the toggle speed of sidebar menu. I am pretty sure it is adjusted by transitions, but for some reason I am having trouble....below is the code I have, and thanks in advance for any help!

```
html:
    <!-- Side Menu -->
     <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>

    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <a id="menu-close" href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg pull-right toggle"><img src="img/portfolio/close-icon-small.png"></a>
            <li class="sidebar-brand"><img src="img/portfolio/ddilogo.png" alt=""></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="homepage.html">Work</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="team.html">team</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- /Side Menu -->


CSS:
/* Side Menu */
#sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-right: -250px;
  right: 0;
  width: 250px;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transition: 0.8s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.8s ease all;
  -ms-transition: 0.8s ease all;
  -o-transition: 0.8s ease all;
  transition: 0.8s ease all;
}

#sidebar-wrapper.active {
  left: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  -webkit-transition:  0.8s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.8s ease all;
  -ms-transition: 0.8s ease all;
  -o-transition: 0.8s ease all;
  transition: 0.8s ease all;
}


JS:
  <script>
    $("#menu-close").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });
    </script>
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: So what **specifically** needs to be changed and what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried adjusting the transition settings from .4s to .8s and nothing changes. The sidebar toggles but there is no transition animation that occurs, the sidebar just appears/disappears without any smooth transition...I would like there to be a smooth (slower) toggle effect.

Comment: You'd have to demo it for us.

Comment: I actually figured it out...just had to change the margins and initial positions to all match. Thanks though for your responses.